# Dialogflow V2 - Custom Contexts

Tags: dialogflow-es

How can I create a custom system context to pass values from my API to dialogflow which is not dependent on any event.
I tried to put the same in the output context, but it is giving error Invalid Argument as the context name doesn't exist.

Here is the below pseudo code which I am doing (Java),
1. define the contextSettings object by setting credentials provider.
2. Create ContextsClient object using contextSettings object.
3. Create CreateContextRequest object by setting parent and context object.
4. Get the final Context object using   ContextsClient.createContext(contextRequest)
5. Set the above context object in queryParameters to pass in DetectIntent Request.

But this is failing in Step # 4, and giving an error as Invalid Argument as the context name is not present under /projects/session

Please help me resolving this issue.

The reason that I want to create custom context is that I need to set values from API to pass to dialogflow and it is independent of Events or a specific flows.

We were able to create custom context in Dialogflow V1 using AIContext class and set the context object in the AIRequest object.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue. I was not passing fully formed context path while creating the context object.

```
Context dialogflowContext = Context.newBuilder().setName(
                    "projects/[project-id]/agent/sessions/" + sessionId + "/contexts/[context-name]")
                    .setParameters(paramPair).setLifespanCount(1).build();
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation about this?